# Может ли GLAD загрузить функции OpenGL из dll файла?

Tags: c++, opengl, dll

Есть функция "init" в dll:

```
void init(const HKCR::WindowProps& props) override {
    m_props = props;

    if (!glfwInit()) {

    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 5);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    m_props.Window = glfwCreateWindow(m_props.Width, m_props.Height, m_props.Title.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr);
    if (m_props.Window == nullptr) {

    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(m_props.Window);
    glfwSetWindowUserPointer(m_props.Window, this);

    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)) {

    }
}
```

.

И почему-то OpenGL функции не загружаются при таком способе. Однако, если я перенесу функцию "gladLoadGLLoader" в "main" функцию (откуда я и использую этот dll), то все ок.

Если честно, то у меня есть только одно предположение почему так происходит. Вроде функция "gladLoadGLLoader" загружает указатели на OpenGL функции в память, а так как загрузка происходила в dll, то об этих загруженных функциях знает только эта dll. Это так? Если нет, то хотелось бы знать, какой правильный ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> так как загрузка происходила в dll, то об этих загруженных функциях знает только эта dll. Это так?

Да. Может быть можно что-то нашаманить, чтобы они грузились сразу на все DLL (собрать GLAD как динамическую библиотеку?), но мы решили вот так: (писать в хедере)

```
inline void LoadGL()
{
    [[maybe_unused]] static const std::nullptr_t once = []{
        gladLoadGLLoader(...);
        return nullptr;
    }();
}
```

И вызывать эту функцию перед манипуляциями с OpenGL. Первый вызов в каждой отдельной DLL вызовет лямбду, а следующие не будут ничего делать.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1):

> так как загрузка происходила в dll, то об этих загруженных функциях знает только эта dll. Это так?

Нет. Все отресовленные GLAD функции становятся доступны для всего процесса. Другое дело, что если использовать GLAD, линкуя его в виде статической библиотеки, либо, еще хуже, как то часто советуют, прямо собирать glad.c вместе с файлами своего проекта, то в программе окажется два набора глобальных переменных, которые GLAD заполняет указателями на соотв. функции - один набор виден в единицах трансляции, составляющих .exe, а другой - в единицах трансляции, составляющих .dll. Ну и вызов `gladLoadGLLoader` будет инициализировать только тот набор, который виден в месте вызова.

¿Что делать? По-хорошему, отказываться от GLAD и прочих динамических загрузчиков и линковать нужные библиотеки, как обычно. На самом деле это не всегда возможно, но стоит использовать более адекватный загрузчик, не плодящий глобальные переменные, и не прячущий их потом за макросами.